# Как настроить генератор случайных чисел для генерации объектов на сайте? (Java Script)

Tags: javascript

Делаю игру машинки на Java Script, нашел исходный код в одном из источников. Там есть функция для генерации случайных чисел, которая вызывается в функции обновления дороги, чтобы в случайном порядке генерировать на ней объекты по типу ям или других машинок. Не могу понять, как мне правильно настроить рандомайзер, чтобы он НЕ генерировал на дороге слишком большое количество этих ям и машинок.
Ниже прилагаю код функции рандомайзера и функции Update для обновления дороги:

```
   function RandomInteger(min, max) 
   {
       let rand = min - 3 + Math.random() * (max - 0 + min + 300);
       return Math.round(rand);
   }
```

```
   function Update() 
   {
      roads[0].Update(roads[1]);
      roads[1].Update(roads[0]);

      if(RandomInteger(0, 20000) > 16000) //Generating new car
      {
          objects.push(new Car("images/cops.png", RandomInteger(1, canvas.width), 
          RandomInteger(15000, 
          1100) * -2, false));
          objects.push(new Car("images/yama.png", RandomInteger(1, canvas.width), 
          RandomInteger(1100, 
          1100) * -1, false));
      }

      player.Update();
      if(player.dead)
      {
         DrawBoom(boom);
         alert("Crash!", a);
         Stop();
      }

      var isDead = false; 

      for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
      {
          objects[i].Update();

          if(objects[i].dead)
          {
              isDead = true;
          }
      }

      if(isDead)
      {
          objects.shift();
      }

      var hit = false;

      for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
      {
          hit = player.Collide(objects[i]);
          if(hit)
          {
              DrawBoom(boom);
              var choose = confirm("Вы врезались! Начать игру заново?");
              if (choose && timer == null)
                  window.location.reload()
              else
                  Stop();
              player.dead = true;
              break;
          }
      }
      Draw();
    }
```

Comment: После `let rand = min - 3 + Math.random() * (max - 0 + min + 300);` даже код читать не хочется...

Comment: @Qwertiy Вопросы не ко мне, а к тому, кому данный код изначально принадлежал, я лишь хочу разобраться в одной конкретной вещи

Comment: `if(RandomInteger(0, 20000) > 16000)` вот здесь меняйте, увеличивайте число `16000`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Спасибо большое!